# trying to send sqlite database file through socket

Tags: java, python, sqlite, android-studio, sockets

i am trying to send a db file from python server to java client, for my school project.

every file is being transferred successfully
However when i try to open the file i get this error:
**"could not open database file. reason database disk image is malformed"**

i am using an python server on my PC

and a android client on my phone
they both are on the same WiFi.

here is the code for the Python server

```
import socket
TCP_IP = '192.168.14.87'
TCP_PORT = 9012

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(5)
print ('listening')
conn, addr=s.accept()
print ("Client connected: ",addr)
filename="trempi.db"
#file=open(filename, 'rb')
#file_data=file.read()
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        bytes_read=f.read()
        if not bytes_read:
            break
        conn.sendall(bytes_read)    
conn.close()
print ("Data has been transmitted :)")
```

And there is the code of the Andorid Client:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        btn=findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn2=findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v==btn2)
        {
            Intent go=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Data.class);
            startActivity(go);
        }
        if (v==btn)
        {
            Thread myThread=new Thread(new MyServer());
            myThread.start();
        }

    }
    class MyServer implements Runnable
    {
        Handler handler=new Handler();
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                byte[] b=new byte[20002];
                Socket s=new Socket("192.168.14.87",9012);
                InputStream is=s.getInputStream();

                FileOutputStream fr=new FileOutputStream(getDatabasePath("trempi.db").toString());
                is.read(b,0,b.length);
                fr.write(b,0,b.length);
                s.close();
                is.close();
                fr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should compare original and damaged file with a hex viewer or editor (also compare sizes).

Comment: the corrupted file is 4 kb less then the original file, and how to spot problems with hex viewer

Comment: I took a closer look now at the Java client: It only reads up to 20002 bytes from socket and writes exactly 20002 bytes, regardless how much data is transferred. The transfer code must be included in a while-loop and break if nothing more is read and the write must only transfer so much bytes as were really read before, not the size of the buffer.

Comment: thank you so much for helping but i dont know how to make a loop of that, i am not expert at java sockets and all the other java socket tutorials didnt use loops

Comment: It's a simple infinite while-loop around the read-write code which should be broken if no more input is coming.

Comment: yeah thank i make it worked, the only problem now is to do the opposite, to  make a python server that receive the file and java client that send the file